# Find PDF of $k$th order statistic

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be continuous random variables with distribution $F$. Let $U_i=F(X_i)$. I have to show that
$$
f_{(k)}(x)=\dfrac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}x^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k},
$$
where $f_{(k)}$ stands for the PDF of the $k$th order statistic. I’ve already shown that
$$
F_{(k)}(x)=\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{n}{j}x^j(1-x)^{n-j}.
$$
Now I tried $f_{(k)}(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}F_{(k)}(x)$, but I'm not sure how to differentiate the binomial. Is it possible to work with induction here? Even then I'm slightly confused, because I would say that we can only go as far up to $n$, and not $\infty$; so would induction be the right word?

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Product rule: $\dfrac{d}{dx} \,\Big(g(x)h(x)\Big) = g'(x) h(x)+g(x) h'(x)$

Comment: Are you conscious that the $U_i$ are uniform ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, I have proven that. So I know that $F_{U_i}(x)=x$.

Comment: Thus, take a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Comment: @JeanMarie I have already looked there and I don't see how that helps. I do notice they mention probability of the order statistic $U_{(k)}$, but they don't explain how they arrive at the expression for it.

Comment: I will just go for a more intuitive approach then.

Comment: In this reference, have you seen the paragraph "Order statistics sampled from a uniform distribution" ? They pretty well explain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate your sum with respect to $x$ and you'll get
$$
\sum_{j=k}^n{n\choose j}\left[ jx^{j-1}(1-x)^{n-j}-(n-j)x^j(1-x)^{n-j-1}\right].
$$
Break this into the *difference* of two sums, the first one being
$$
A:=\sum_{j=k}^n{n\choose j} jx^{j-1}(1-x)^{n-j}
=\sum_{j=k}^n\frac{n!}{(j-1)!(n-j)!} x^{j-1}(1-x)^{n-j}
$$
and the second one
$$
B:=\sum_{j=k}^n{n\choose j}(n-j)x^j(1-x)^{n-j-1}
\stackrel{(*)}=\sum_{j=k}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{j!(n-j-1)!}x^j(1-x)^{n-j-1}
$$
In the sum on the left of (*) we notice the $j=n$ term is zero, so stop the sum at $j=n-1$. Next, change index of summation to $i:=j+1$ and you get
$$
B=\sum_{i=k+1}^n\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!}x^{i-1}(1-x)^{n-i}.
$$
Now we see that $A$ minus $B$ is a single term, and you're done.

Comment: Many, many thanks. I didn't realise I could write $j$ and $n-j$ in the binomial term, but of course, once you do that, you're practically there, apart from a change in index. Again, really, thanks so much.

Comment: @ShaVuklia Happy to help. It's not obvious that you should write out the binomial coefficient, or change index of summation. A good strategy is to write out a small case such as $n=3, k=1$, which will lead you to discover that $A$ and $B$ share terms in common.